# Why can't I find a game when playing with friends?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Since 3 days I can't figure out why I can't play a game with friends.

When I start a game alone, works.

When I make/join a lobby we can't find any servers. It only says "Searching Servers..." and the expected wait time just raises to over 9000...

But I've started CS:GO on my Macbook and it worked on the same network so it has to be a problem with my Windows machine.

Things I've already done:

- flushed steam config
- checked files of csgo - multiple times.
- turned off antivirus (avast)
- turned off windows firewall
- reset start params and custom autoexec commands
- reinstalled cs:go - to other location

Still the same problem - any Ideas without resetting my windows?

Comment: Did you check your hosts file? You might have the CS:GO MM servers blocked.

Comment: How about the maximum matchmaking ping CS:GO setting?

Comment: Have you tried only MM or other game modes?  Are any of your friends using family sharing?

Comment: I tried Deathmatch, Casual and Comp. - I will try the max ping setting. - Also sometimes the other people are joining and I stay alone in the lobby with an error message that the original lobby creator has left.

Comment: I have family sharing activated for some friends but everybody has a copy of cs:go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why & how this is a problem but I had to download [`Matchmaking Server Picker`](http://csgo.gamebanana.com/tools/5684) and choose the closest servers in my region (Germany => EU West/East/North)

And now it works somehow - no more issues with any connection - ranks aren't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First off it depends on your ranks. If you are 5 people all over the place:
Sliver 1, Gold Nova 1, Master Guardian 2 and two Global Elites (for instance) It will be really hard for the MM system to find an appropriate group of enemies to match you with.

Secondly, even though it was around six months ago, it may still have not been patched: When me and friends were MMing it would depends who hosted, sometimes - randomly it would act up like it does for you. Also you can kinda feel when it won't match you up, so the easiest thing to do was to press the X and start looking for a server again - restarting the match-making, most of the times this would fix it for us.

Comment: Yeah, currently it works - sometimes it's not working. I always run server-picker so I only get Servers with a good ping and we switch the lobby creator what helps often. - Still the MM-system is buggy as hell.

Comment: True, but there are other bugs to clear out right now, balance the revolver, and apparently if a smoke is up, and you Alt+Tab you can see trough it afterwards ...

Comment: Jep. Sad that development on this things is to slow and there is no beta with community feedback.